# How to pass the List of class objects from Web Service to Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, web-services, list, return

I have a problem with passing a list of objects from a `WebService` to my `WinForms` app.
I've created a class **`Osoba`** in the `WebService` with a method returning the list of class objects.
The code of this method looks like this by now:

```
public List<Osoba> ListaOsoba()
{
    Osoba nr1 = new Osoba(1,"Name1","Surname1",Uprawnienia.Administrator);
    Osoba nr2 = new Osoba(2,"Name2","Surname2",Uprawnienia.Uzytkownik);
    Osoba nr3 = new Osoba(3,"Name3","Surname3",Uprawnienia.Uzytkownik);

    listaOsób.Add(nr1);
    listaOsób.Add(nr2);
    listaOsób.Add(nr3);

    return listaOsób;
}
```

In the app, I've added a reference to the `WebService`, that contains the `Osoba` class.
My app code looks like this (*localhost* is my `WebService` object):

```
public void SprawdzUprawnienie()
{
    foreach (var item in webServiceComarch.ListaOsoba())
    {
       localhost.Osoba nowaOsoba = new localhost.Osoba();
       nowaOsoba(item.indentyfikator, item.imie, item.nazwisko, item.Uprawnienia);
       listaOsob.Add(nowaOsoba);
    }
}
```

I get an error

> nowaOsoba is a "variable" but is used like a "method".

at the line

```
nowaOsoba(item.indentyfikator, item.imie, item.nazwisko, item.Uprawnienia);
```

I've searched through a lot of information on the Web about this kind of problem, but nothing really helped me.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Any tips will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
foreach (var item in webServiceComarch.ListaOsoba())
{
  nowaOsoba.indentyfikator = item.indentyfikator;
  nowaOsoba.imie = item.imie;
  ....
  ....
  ....
  listaOsob.Add(nowaOsoba);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var data= nowaOsoba.nowaOsoba(item.indentyfikator, item.imie, item.nazwisko, item.Uprawnienia);
listaOsob.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ServiceClient for your WebService and use that client to call the ListaOsoba() method. This should lokk something like that:

```
var client = new YourWebServiceClient();
var list = client.ListaOsoba();
```

YourWebServiceClient is a placeholder and will differ acording to the name you have choosen for your actual WebService.